# SQL Server Format() function

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, format

I have a current query in an MS Access database that uses the Format() function to convert a number (long integer) to a string.

The table has been redesigned and moved to SQL server. The field I need to convert is not a money field that I need to drop everything after the period and convert it to a string with a certain number of characters.

Sample Data:

```
Amount
228.00000
1896.00000
6411.00000
317.00000
4830.00000
898.00000
1778.00000
1308.00000
45139.00000
424.00000
```

Current MS Access query:

```
SELECT Format(CallAmt],"000000000000000") AS Amount
FROM Fed
```

New query:

```
SELECT Convert(varchar(15), FedAmount)
FROM Fed.SM_T_Call
```

I would like my final Product to look like this:

```
Amount
000000000000228
000000000001896
000000000006411
000000000000317
000000000004830
000000000000898
000000000001778
000000000001308
000000000045139
000000000000424
```

I don't know how to drop everything after the period and add the extra zeros to my result. Can anyone offer any assistance?

Comment: What datatype is FedAmount in SQL Server? You said its not a money field, what is it in SQL Server after it was moved

Comment: It would help if you edit your question and show how you want the final output to look.

Comment: yep, need final output. Not all of us bother with/use VBA.

Comment: my bad, I edited to add my final product. sorry.

Comment: Use my RIGHT solution then to have leading spaces with a CAST to int

Comment: This looks to me like a presentation-layer issue, not a SQL issue at all, so if your front end is still in Access, you should be able to continue using Format().

Comment: @David-W-Fenton front-end is no longer going to be in Access.  We actually are exporting the data in a text file and it needs to be in a certain format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

- CAST to decimal to have a fixed number of decimal places
- Use STR to right justify
- Use `RIGHT('000000000000000' + CAST(MyNumber AS varchar(15)), 15)` to have leading zeros

Or all of the above: but we don't know what output you want...

Edit, after update

```
RIGHT('000000000000000' + CAST(CAST(Amount AS int) AS varchar(15)), 15)
```

Edit, October 2011

SQL Server 2012 (Denali) will have Format function.

Edit, after comment by onedaywhen

```
DECLARE @len tinyint;
SET @len = 15;
RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', @len) + CAST(CAST(Amount AS int) AS varchar(255)), @len)
```

Comment: thank you so much.  I had no clue how I was going to figure this out.  Sorry again for not including sample data.

Comment: Using `REPLICATE('0', 15)` would make your code easier to read.

Comment: @onedaywhen: True. In real life I'd probably wrap it in a UDF and have length as a parameter...

Answer (score 0):

```
select Cast(Cast(fedamount as int), as varchar(15))
from Fed.SM_T_Call
```

Might actually work?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(FLOOR(FedAmont) AS INT) AS VARCHAR(40)) + '.00'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the decimal data type:

```
declare @var decimal(15,6)
set @var = 228564.12345678
```

And then if you want it to be a varchar after that:

```
select convert(varchar(15),@var)
```

Or in a select, it could look like this:

```
select 
   [field1] as OldValue,
   convert(decimal(15,6),[field1]) as NewValue
from 
   myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

@gbn'd answer is a good one for SQL Server and uses proprietary functions `RIGHT()` and `REPLICATE()`.

Noting that you've already had to port this once, the following may be a more portable version because it uses Standard SQL functions. Note the string concatenation operator in Standard SQL is `||`, whereas SQL Server uses `+` for the same (and MS still claims it is compliant, go figure). However, the proposed code still scores highly on the portability scale because transforming `` `|| `` to `+` is trivial:

```
REVERSE(CAST(REVERSE(CAST(CAST(Amount AS INTEGER) AS VARCHAR(15))) 
   + '000000000000000' AS CHAR(15)))
```